# how to find all extended classes from package/single java file using reflection in java?

Tags: java, reflection

Suppose I use a single Java file which contains 2 classes like A & B
(B extends A).

Then how can I find class A using reflection in Java?

Are there any methods present in Java reflection to get all super classes?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html

Comment: @Shloim - That question is about finding all subclasses.  The OP wants to find all superclasses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Then how can I find class A using reflection in Java?

Call `Class.getSuperclass()`.  It returns the superclass, or `null` if there isn't one.

> Are there any methods present in Java reflection to get all super classes?

No there aren't.  However, you can trivially find all superclasses of a class with a loop; e.g.

```
    public List<Class> getAllSuperclasses(Class cls) {
        List<Class> res = new ArrayList<>();
        while ((cls = cls.getSuperclass()) != null) {
            res.add(cls);
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
B object;

Class subclass = object.getClass();
Class superclass = subclass.getSuperclass();
```